# Why does Avanthika have no dialogues in Baahubali The Conclusion?

Tags: plot-explanation, baahubali-2-the-conclusion

In *Baahubali II*, why does Avanthika's role have no dialogues?

Is there any reason for it? They completely neglected this character - why?

In the first movie they showed this role very well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Aslam Khan character was introduced when he had no further siginificance?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73403/why-aslam-khan-character-was-introduced-when-he-had-no-further-siginificance)

Comment: This question I linked to has an answer that also explains this. Also she had a few dialogues.